# grey view on table search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a search and i want when it's clicked to dispaly  the last table with results , I did this but i get :

[image]

How can I remove that grey view  ?

I was trying to use this , but no result :

```
    - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden=NO;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar bringSubviewToFront:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView];

    [self.search becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

for (UIView *v in [[[controller.searchResultsTableView superview] superview] subviews]) {

    if (v.frame.origin.y == 64) {
        [v setHidden:YES];
    }
  }

}
```